# Error in code after calling a library in RStudio

Tags: r, compiler-errors, latex

I have been writing a code in RStudio and using TinyTex to compile my pdf. I wrote the following code in an RSweave file in RStudio:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{boxy}[1]{colback=green!5!white, colframe=green!75!black, title={#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=astral,
    filecolor=astral,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=astral
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\makeatletter
\title{\textbf{\underline{Assignment 2}}}\let\thetitle\@title
\author{Devansh Kamra}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{boxy}{Question No. 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|. What do you see?
    \item How many rows are in \verb|mpg|? How many columns?
    \item What does the \verb|drv| variable describe? Read the help for \verb|?mpg| to find out.
    \item Make a scatterplot of \verb|hwy| vs \verb|cyl|.
    \item What happens if you make a scatterplot of class vs drv? Why is the plot not useful?
  \end{enumerate}
\end{boxy}

\section*{\underline{Solution:}}
  \subsection*{\underline{Part 1}}
    Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:
    <<>>=
    ggplot(data = mpg)
    @
    We can easily see that \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)| gives us an empty plane to plot the data on.

\end{document}
```

It gives me this output pdf:
[image]

It says it couldn't find function `ggplot`, which is completely understandable as I didn't load `library("tidyverse")` yet. but it is compiling the pdf, by which I assume there is no LaTeX error as such. Now I simply add `library("tidyverse")` to the previous code:

```
%%same code before
Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:
    <<>>=
    library("tidyverse")
    ggplot(data = mpg)
    @
%%same code after
```

But now I'm getting following errors after compiling and it doesn't produce a pdf.

```
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: assign2.Rnw
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ indent: chr "    "

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: assign2.tex

[1] "assign2.tex"
Compiling document with tinytex ... ! Undefined control sequence.
\f@nch@orh ->\theauthor 
                        \strut 
l.132 \end{document}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile D:/hp/Desktop/assign2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See assign2.log for more info.
Execution halted
failed

Bad Box: pgf.sty:120: Overfull \hbox (32.5757pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 120--121
Bad Box: pgf.sty:124: Overfull \hbox (68.61136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 124--124
Bad Box: pgf.sty:128: Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 128--131
Error: pgf.sty:132: Undefined control sequence.
Error: pgf.sty:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Now I might be wrong about this, but overfull \hbox errors are generally LaTeX errors, and if they are, then why didn't they show before loading `library("tidyverse")`? Kindly help me out rectify these errors, and I apologize if this is trivial, for I am new to R.

**EDIT:** The code gives me a perfectly compiled pdf once I remove the following chunk:

```
%%same code before
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
%%same code after
```

This apparently means that I am unable to use package `fancyhdr` in my code. Why is that, and is there any possible way I can resolve the issue so that I am able to use the package?

Comment: But it plots the required plot even without using that library after removing fancyhdr. I assume that the mentioned library is already present in tidyverse. How do I use fancyhdr package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is completely unrelated to any r libraries. The reason why you only see it if you fix the r errors is that then your document is more than one page long and you actually get to see your fancy headers (the first page uses a different pagestyle, thus no error with only one page).

As the error messages says, the actual problem is that `\theauthor`  is not defined. You manually define it for the title, you must also define it for the author.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{AddToHook}{}{\AddToHook{package/xcolor/after}{\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\let\hlipl\hlkwb

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{AddToHook}{}{\AddToHook{package/xcolor/after}{
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{boxy}[1]{colback=green!5!white, colframe=green!75!black, title={#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=astral,
    filecolor=astral,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=astral
}


\makeatletter

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\title{\textbf{\underline{Assignment 2}}}\let\thetitle\@title
\author{Devansh Kamra}\let\theauthor\@author
\makeatother
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}




\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{boxy}{Question No. 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|. What do you see?
    \item How many rows are in \verb|mpg|? How many columns?
    \item What does the \verb|drv| variable describe? Read the help for \verb|?mpg| to find out.
    \item Make a scatterplot of \verb|hwy| vs \verb|cyl|.
    \item What happens if you make a scatterplot of class vs drv? Why is the plot not useful?
  \end{enumerate}
\end{boxy}

\section*{\underline{Solution:}}
  \subsection*{\underline{Part 1}}
    Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:

    
    \newpage
    
    test
    
    \newpage
    
    test

\end{document}
```

Comment: After adding `\let\theauthor\@author` after `\author{Devansh Kamra}`, it works perfectly. I am extremely grateful to you for taking time in helping me out with such a trivial error. Thanks a lot!